# Running perl code out of cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

My perl code which locates certain modules can run perfectly fine from the command line and gives no errors. But if I want to run it out of cygwin it gives me the error

```
 0 [main] perl 3960 handle_exceptions: Error while dumping
state (probably corrupted stack).
```

I am using use lib to locate my modules.

I was wondering if the problem is specifically with cygwin?

Comment: You might want to state which version of perl, etc

Comment: what does "run it out of cygwin" mean?  does that use a different perl?  show your 'use lib'

Comment: As in put use 5.010; into my code? Run it out of Cygwin just means I open the cygwin termnial and run my script in that terminal rather than the command window. No I dont use a different perl. My use lib is just something like use lib 'folder1', 'folder2' etc.

Comment: Actually, are you sure you're not using cygwin's `perl`? You can't use modules installed using a Windows build of Perl with a cygwin build of Perl.

Comment: how do I figure out which version of perl to use then?

Comment: Two options.... run `perl -v` out of cygwin and out of command line to see if the versions and builds are the same. Or, temporarily rename one of your 2 perl.exe files, e.g. as zzzperl.exe and run perl again and see if it works from cygwin and command line - if either no longer works that means the one you renamed was the one it was using.

Comment: So my command line version of perl is v5.8.4 and my cygwin is v5.10.1. Does this mean I need to specify in my perl script to run 5.10.1? If I do need to do that how would I go about it?